# Facebook Mobile hosting api for App links is not working in Android

Tags: android, facebook, share, applinks

I'm trying to make App Links work with my Android app. I have successfully created App-links from wen HTML page(with meta-tags) and its work fine with redirection to my application from Facebook. But when i try with the facebook mobile hosting api which allow us to create app links without help of any server or web page, I Found some serious confusion in facebook documentations.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api
I can not get idea How to call api using this below code :

`

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/app/app_link_hosts \
-F access_token="APP_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F name="Android App Link Object Example" \
-F android=' [
    {
      "url" : "sharesample://story/1234",
      "package" : "com.facebook.samples.sharesample",
      "app_name" : "ShareSample",
    },
  ]' \
-F web=' {
    "should_fallback" : false,
  }'
```

`

And can any one give some idea regarding how we can call api from android application to achieve app linking.

Answer (score 0):

I work for a company called [Branch.io](http://branch.io). We are deep linking company that provides solutions for Android App Links, Facebook App Links, etc... all build into one link. The issue is Facebook is difficult to deal with and their links break in a lot of cases. You can convince yourself here. [Deep Linking from Facebook in 2017](https://blog.branch.io/deep-linking-from-facebook-in-2017/)

We actually support link hosting, so you should be able to use us without hosting your own web domain and we will make the API calls for you. We support Facebook links all within our own links with simple use of OpenGraph parameters within our links.

[OpenGraph Parameters in Branch Links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aw2Y.png)

Conceptually, on the inside a Branch link looks like this:

```
{
    tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2' ],
    channel: 'facebook',
    feature: 'dashboard',
    stage: 'new user',
    alias: 'myalias',
    data: {
        mydata: 'something',
        foo: 'bar',
        '$desktop_url': 'http://myappwebsite.com',
        '$ios_url': 'http://myappwebsite.com/ios',
        '$android_url': 'http://myappwebsite.com/android',
        '$og_app_id': '12345',
        '$og_title': 'My App',
        '$og_description': 'My app\'s description.',
        '$og_image_url': 'http://myappwebsite.com/image.png'
    }
}
```

With this you can attach any metadata you would like and can therefore support your dynamic content with deep linking while covering Facebook links, as well as, nearly every other platform and device. We also cover [deferred deep linking](https://branch.io/what-is-deep-linking/) which is not supported with Facebook App links.

For the basic deep linking that you are looking for, the service is free.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But if i don't want to use any third party API , than what is the solution ?